# Sending Templated emails with node.js, node mailer and nodemailer-mailgun-transport

Tags: express, handlebars.js, mailgun, nodemailer, transport

I have the following basic nodejs app:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');
var options = {
 viewEngine: {
     extname: '.hbs',
     layoutsDir: 'views/email/',
     defaultLayout : 'template',
     partialsDir : 'views/partials/'
 },
 viewPath: 'views/email/',
 extName: '.hbs'
};

var mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');

var auth = {
    auth: {
        api_key: ' mailgun api key ',
        domain: ' mailgun email domain '
    }
}

var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth));

mailer.use('compile', hbs(options));
mailer.sendMail({
 from: 'test@inventori.io',
 to: 'test@test.com',
 subject: 'Any Subject',
 template: 'email.body',
 context: {
      variable1 : 'value1',
      variable2 : 'value2'
 }
}, function (error, response) {
    // console.error(error);
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    };
 console.log('mail sent to ',response);
 mailer.close();
});
```

views/email/template.hbs

```
{{>email/head}}
<body>
     {{>email/header}}
     {{{body}}}
     {{>email/footer}}
</body>
</html>
```

views/email/email.body.hbs

```
<h4>Main Body Here</h4>
{{variable1}} <br/>
{{variable2}}
```

views/partials/email/header.hbs

```
<h4>Header Content</h4>
```

views/partials/email/footer.hbs

```
<h4>Footer Content</h4>
```

The handlebars template engine gives zero errors but the mailgun transport throws the following error:

```
Error: Sorry: template parameter is not supported yet. Check back soon!
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (~/test/node_modules/nodemailer-mailgun-transport/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/request.js:228:15)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

This example uses the gmail node mailer transport:

```
http://excellencenodejsblog.com/express-nodemailer-sending-mails/
```

I would like to be able to send templated emails using mailgun.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `template` parameter to `html`.

If you look at the [source code here](https://github.com/orliesaurus/nodemailer-mailgun-transport/blob/master/src/mailgun-transport.js#L42-L50), the error correct- there is no such thing as a `template` parameter.

Comment: The link here is not valid

Comment: It looks like the nodemailer-mailgun-transport API has been updated https://github.com/orliesaurus/nodemailer-mailgun-transport/blob/master/src/index.js#L114 and appears to accept a `template` parameter now. Perhaps you can try that out.

Answer (score 2):

For me, templates weren't rendering properly because I was following an example using `extName` when the key was actually `extname` (all lowercase). Perhaps it was renamed overtime and the guide I was looking at is now somewhat out of date.

**Full working example below as of 30 May 2020.**

Directory Structure:

```
root/
   src/
      email-templates/
              layouts/
                     blank.hbs
              partials/
              hello.hbs
      services/
              email.service.ts
```

**email.service.ts** (Haven't updated this to use proper types yet. Just a poc.)

```js
export async function sendTestEmail() {
  try {
    // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
    // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
    const testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount()

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
        pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
      },
    })

    transporter.use('compile', hbs({
      viewEngine: {
        extname: '.hbs', // handlebars extension
        partialsDir: 'src/email-templates',
        layoutsDir: 'src/email-templates/layouts',
        defaultLayout: 'blank',
      },
      viewPath: 'src/email-templates',
      extName: '.hbs'
    }))

    // send mail with defined transport object
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'test@gmail.com', // sender address
      to: 'test@gmail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
      text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
      template: 'hello',
      context: {
        firstName: 'Clem'
      }
    }
    const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId)
    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same code, the emails are sent when I use `text` instead of `template`, but with `template` I get the following error on Mailgun ```"description": "Failed to render template",```

Comment: You saved me! Dude, I'm so grateful to you for this post. extName in viewEngine object was the reason why it didn't work for me.